# Windows: Prevent access to a drive for a user?

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, logical-drive

Using Windows Vista.  What is the correct and best way to prevent access to an entire drive (not the C windows drive) for a particular user?  Probably I prefer an NTFS solution rather than hiding drive letters.

When I look on the Security tab of the drive's properties I see:

Group or usernames:

```
Authenticated Users
SYSTEM
Administrators (MyComputer\Administrators)
Users (MyComputer\Users)
```

I'm not sure if I should be adding a deny permission or removing an existing permission and I don't understand how the Authenticated Users combines with Users (or with the specific user if I add them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Deny" permissions overrule "Allow". When Windows encounters a Deny that matches the current user, it stops looking and denies the access. It therefore doesn't matter how many groups would allow your particular user, once you've denied him, he's out.

Comment: So you're saying add that user and then mark them as deny read?

Comment: I figured I'd give this a shot.  It looks like windows is going through every single file on that drive and adjusting the permissions.  Is that right?