# Windows: Give access to a drive only for given user(s)?

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, logical-drive

Using Windows Vista. What is the correct and best way to limit access to an entire drive (not the C windows drive) for *all* users except certain specified users (adhering to principle of least privilege)?

When I look on the Security tab of the drive's properties I see:

Group or usernames:

```
Authenticated Users
SYSTEM
Administrators (MyComputer\Administrators)
Users (MyComputer\Users)
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Windows: Prevent access to a drive for a user?](http://superuser.com/questions/337896/windows-prevent-access-to-a-drive-for-a-user)

Comment: Incorrect.  That question is about letting *all* users access a given drive except a specific user.  This question is about letting *no* users access a given drive except a specified user.

Comment: Im guessing this is for other users accessing one PC as opposed to a server?

Comment: @CodeBlend correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "Authenticated Users" and "Users" and add the group or usernames you want given access.

If there are already existing files on the drive, you may want to use the "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object" option in order to give them the same restrictions.

This will not stop people with access to the drive from changing the permissions on their own files to grant access to other people.

Comment: Now, after having done that, would there be a way to access that drive while logged in as a user that is not on the permitted list (maybe using runas or something)?  The scenario I'm thinking of is if I'm logged in under that user and I want to temporarily view or copy a file.

Comment: Certainly, provided you are willing to access it from the command line or from within an application.  For the command line, you could use RunAs, or you could type "cmd" in the Start Menu and press control-shift-ENTER to bring up the elevation prompt.  For other apps, start them from the command line or right-click and select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: What I mean by "from the command line or within an application" is that you can't use Explorer, because it doesn't support elevation.  There are third-party file manager apps that can be used as an alternative to Explorer.

Comment: You don't need to elevate Explorer. Just `Runas` with the correct credentials.

Comment: @surfasb, there are some tasks (such as looking at file properties) that can't easily be done except from Explorer or a third-party alternative.